# Filter Array if Current Time is within TimeRange

Tags: swift, parse-platform, filtering

My current function filters the array and returns an array of `PFObjects` with only `"Type"` = `"Sushi"`. Now, I am **trying to filter the array if current time is within a time range (`"OpenHours"` and `"CloseHours"`)** 
The new Function passes `dayOfWeek: Int`, `timeNow: String`

"OpenHours" Example: [0, 6] = [sunday, monday]

```
["0011","0011","0011","0011","0011","0011","0011"]
```

"CloseHours" Example:

```
["2350","2350","2350","2350","2350","2350","2350"]
```

Current Function that filters "Type":

```
  func filterRestaurants(filteredObject: String) {
 //func filterOpenNow(dayOfWeek: Int, timeNow: String){
    filteredRestaurantArray = unfilteredRestaurantArray.filter() {
        if let type = ($0 as PFObject)["Type"] as? String { // Get value of PFObject
            return type.rangeOfString("Sushi") != nil
        } else {
            println("nope")
            return false
        }
    }
```

Basically I need to filter for objects where current time `timeNow` is between `OpenHours` and `CloseHours` for a given `dayOfWeek`

**Edit:** 
What I've Tried so far:
I'm unsure how to get the position of a value in the PFObject array. Normal I would check if the timeNow is between OpenNow[dayOfWeek] and CloseNow[dayOfWeek]

Something like this (except with filter):

```
if OpenNow[dayOfWeek] ... CloseNow[dayOfWeek] ~= timeNow {
    println("success")
}
```

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh I added what I've tried so far. Mostly the thought process, as I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Comment: This may require you to change the way you're representing "times", but have you looked into CMTime, CMTimeRange, CMTimeRangeMake, and CMTimeRangeContainsTime? These may or may not be useful to you, but they do provide the type of functionality you're looking for. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTimeRange/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMTimeRangeContainsTime

Comment: @michaelavila thanks for the suggestion. it looks like CMTimeRange uses `StartTime` and `Duration`. Since I'm dealing with restaurants, I would need to use `Open` and `Close` times (calculating the duration for each day for each restaurant seems like a lot of added processing).

Comment: @Rachel, that's understandable. An alternative way to look at it is that you're trading work with the computer, i.e. if the computer does a little extra work to translate the times to a different format you can do less work writing the logic to work with the times in your format. Though, I definitely understand that every situation is different. I would be remiss if I didn't mention it. Take care! And good luck!

Comment: So to be clear, you first are filtering by type, then you want to filter those results further by if they are open currently? And the objects are of type `PFObject`?

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh Thanks, the new filter will replace the filter by `type`. I would only like to filter results if they are open currently. Yes, the objects are `PFObjects`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what the properties of your `PFObject` instance are, so I'm going to make some assumptions and you will have to correct the keys to meet your needs.

Working with the function signature you provided is not entirely possible. This is because in order for it to work you would be accessing a list of `PFObject`s that were not provided to the function. While Swift does not keep you from doing that, it is generally not a wise design choice as you cannot be confident of the results of the function at any given point in time. So, to provide what is called [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)) we will modify your function to also take in the collection of `PFObject`s.

With that collection we will then use the native `filter` function to determine which ones to return from the function. The `filter` function takes a collection and a closure. The closure takes one parameter, an element of the collection, and return a `Bool`. The closure is what determines if an element is kept or discarded.

Knowing that, we can build up the functionality you requested. I cannot guarantee there isn't a better way to do the first `if let` dance at the beginning, but it should get the job done.

```
func filterAreOpen(restaurants: [PFObject], forTime time: String, onDay day: Int) -> [PFObject] {
    let openRests = filter(restaurants) { r in
        if let openHours = r["OpenHours"] as AnyObject? as? [String] {
            if let closeHours = r["CloseHours"] as AnyObject? as? [String] {
                switch (openHours[day].toInt(), closeHours[day].toInt(), time.toInt()) {
                case let (.Some(oh), .Some(ch), .Some(t)):
                    return oh...ch ~= t
                default: 
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    return openRests
}
```

And you would use it like this

```
let rests = [ // example objects that are replaced by your PFObject instances
              [
                "OpenHours":["0011","0012","0013"],
                "CloseHours":["0023","0023","0023"],
                "Name":"Restaurant1"
              ], 
              [
                "OpenHours":["0014","0015","0016"],
                "CloseHours":["0020","0020","0020"],
                "Name":"Restaurant2"
              ]
            ]
let openRestaurants = filterAreOpen(rests, forTime: "0012", onDay: 1)
/* Results
    [{
        CloseHours =     (
            0023,
            0023,
            0023
        );
        Name = Restaurant1;
        OpenHours =     (
            0011,
            0012,
            0013
        );
    }]
*/
```

---

#### Edit:

A quick explanation about the `switch` inside the closure. In Swift the `switch` statement is much more powerful than it was in the Objective-C days. It is capable of matching a value against a pattern, not just numbers.

So, in this case, the `switch` is matching a 3-tuple of `Int?`, `(Int?, Int?, Int?)`. This is because `String`'s `toInt()` method returns an `Int?`. `switch` is also able to bind matched patterns to local scoped constants. To do that we use the `let` keyword. To pattern match on an `Optional` value, you use the `.Some(x)` pattern. Since we have a 3-tuple we use `.Some(x)` three time, with the `x` replaced by some meaningful name. This way we have access to the three values we are interested in if the three `toInt()` calls evaluated to non-`nil` values.

If any of the `String` values could not evaluate to an `Int`, and so was `nil`, the `default` case is used, and returns false.

You can view the language book on conditional statements [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_197).

Comment: that worked perfectly! thank you. I'm still trying to learn to code better. Would you mind explaining what the code is doing (specifically what the switch statement is doing)?

Comment: @Rachel please review my edit to the answer. Hopefully that will help you understand what is happening in the `switch`.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation! I think I understand what's going on now :)