# Sort Array based on other Sorted Array

Tags: sorting, swift

I have two arrays of the same size and I sort the second one. How can I array the first one to match?

Basic example (imagine replacing `Ints` with `Strings`):

```
var array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

var array2 = [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1] 

array2.sort = ({ $0 > $1})
```

Result:

```
array2 is now [8, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

How to sort array1's index value to match array2?

```
array1 should now be [6, 5, 0, 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: I would say make one array of object and sort object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Zip2`, `sorted` and `map`

```
array1 = map(sorted(Zip2(array1, array2), {$0.1 > $1.1}), { $0.0 })
```

---

Combining `filter`

```
var array1 = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
var array2 = [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1]

func isEven(x:Int) -> Bool {
    return x % 2 == 0
}

let result = map(sorted(filter(Zip2(array1, array2), { isEven($0.1) }), {$0.1 > $1.1}), { $0.0 })
// -> ["6", "5", "3", "8", "1"]
```

As you can see, the line is too complex, you might want to `Array` method chain syntax:

```
let result2 = Array(Zip2(array1, array2))
    .filter({ isEven($0.1) })
    .sorted({ $0.1 > $1.1 })
    .map({ $0.0 })
```

Anyway, if your `array2` is `[PFObject]`, you can implement the function something like:

```
func isOpen(restaurant: PFObject, forTime time: String, onDay day: Int) -> Bool {

    // return `true` if the restaurant is open, `false` otherwise

}
```

Comment: Does this work for functions too? If I call a function for array2 `filterAreOpen(detailsForFoodPhotos, forTime: time.time, onDay: time.dayOfWeek)` and map array1 the same way?

Comment: Would it look something like this: `map(filterAreOpen(detailsForFoodPhotos, forTime: time.time, onDay: time.dayOfWeek), { $0.0 })`

Comment: what is `filterAreOpen`, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27879386/3804019)? If so, I don't think it will work. I will add the basic example combining `filter`.

Comment: Thank you so much. But will the filter work if my `filterAreOpen` function returns an array? Or will I need to create a new function that can filter individual data? (please see edited question)

Comment: The latter: you need to create a new function. It's not so hard, your `filterAreOpen` already have `filter` logic. You can extract that.