# Sorting array based on other array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays in java

```
int[] num={5,2,10,12,4};
String[] name={"a","b","g","c","r"};
```

if I sort the int array in ascending order,it'll be :

```
int[] num={2,4,5,10,12};
```

now I want to sort the name array accordingly.
The output should be :

```
String[] name={"b","r","a","g","c"};
```

how can I maintain a relation?
I've seen this link([Sort Array based on other Sorted Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426150/sort-array-based-on-other-sorted-array)),but its for js

Comment: but what is the relationship betwen both arrays???

Comment: I just want to sort an array based on the sorting order of another array. Please read the entire question.

Comment: I got your question, but have you tried writing something for this? We are here to help if you are stuck. We won't write code for you.

Comment: You can use 2 auxiliar arrays to do that

Comment: You could convert it all to a `TreeMap` and then extract the values again.

Comment: Not really but got some idea : 
like,if I can get the changing order of the 1st array(the order of rearranged index),I can apply that for 2nd array.
But sorry,didn't write anything, getting a bit confused 
You dont have to write code,just help me a bit with idea.Thanks.
@Maverick

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to want to do, so maybe think about whether you are using the correct data structures.

Comment: You have to convert your idea into code :) then if you are stuck then paste code here. We will be happy to help you.

Comment: My suggestion is you change your design. See [Anti-pattern:Parallel Collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/). If you follow the guidance given there, you can use standard sorting methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,it was easy :

```
int[] num={5,2,10,12,4};
String[] name={"a","b","g","c","r"};
int tempNum;
String tempName;

for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j++) 
            {
                if (num[i] > num[j]) 
                {
                    tempNum = num[i];
                    tempName=name[i];

                    num[i] = num[j];
                    name[i] = name[j];

                    num[j] = tempNum;
                    name[j] = tempName;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom class with the combined data, i.e. one integer variable and one string variable. This class would implement the Comparable interface and override its compareTo() method. Then create an array of objects of this class, and sort it using normal Arrays.sort() function of util library.

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
    int num;
    String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data data) {
        return this.num - data.num;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Data[] data = new Data[5];
// initialize data
Arrays.sort(data)
// now the num will be sorted in ascending order and name will be shuffled accordingly
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Java 8 Streams API

You can build a stream of all valid indexes, sort that stream according to the `num` array and then map the indexes to the `name` values and collect them in a new array.

```
String[] nameSorted = IntStream.range(0, num.length).boxed()
        .sorted((i, j) -> Integer.compare(num[i], num[j]))
        .map(i -> name[i])
        .toArray(x -> new String[x]);
```

And if needed (due to `name` array passed as reference to be "sorted" in-place), just copy the sorted values to the original array:

```
System.arraycopy(nameSorted, 0, name, 0, name.length);
```

Note that this way the array `num` is left untouched.

---

#### Using a custom implementation of Bubble Sort

As already figured out by the asker and mentioned by Jayanand the task is also easily accomplished by swapping elements in both array simultaneously whenever the sorting algorithm instructs to do so.

An implementation that uses both arrays directly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < num.length; j++) {
        if (num[i] > num[j]) {
            int tempNum = num[i];
            String tempName = name[i];
            num[i] = num[j];
            name[i] = name[j];
            num[j] = tempNum;
            name[j] = tempName;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the logic and the value access separated so that Bubble Sort can be used for virtually any flavour indexed data structure:

```
public static void bubbleSort(int length, IntBinaryOperator comparator,
        BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> swapOperation) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++)
            if (comparator.applyAsInt(i, j) > 0)
                swapOperation.accept(i, j);
}

bubbleSort(num.length, 
        (i, j) -> Integer.compare(num[i], num[j]), 
        (i, j) -> {
            int tempNum = num[i];
            String tempName = name[i];
            num[i] = num[j];
            name[i] = name[j];
            num[j] = tempNum;
            name[j] = tempName;
        });
```

As the average complexity of Bubble Sort is *O(n²)* (see [its description at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)) it doesn't make much sense to rant about unnecessary integer boxing and unboxing here.

---

#### Using data objects

Create a new class for objects keeping both `num` and `name` value:

```
class Item {
    int num;
    String name;
    Item(int num, String name) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now if you have e.g. a `List<Item> items` it can be easily sorted using:

```
items.sort(Comparator.comparing(item -> item.num));
```

To create such a list from your arrays you could use (similarly to using Streams API for sorting):

```
List<Item> items = IntStream.range(0, num.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Item(num[i], name[i]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

#### Summary

What could be considered the *best* solution heavily depends on the particular use case that you have.

If you have no choice but working with those two arrays because they are passed to you in the context of some API or project where you are unable to change the design *Bubble Sort* with customized comparison and swap operations is definitely to be considered as long as you don't have thounsands of values to be sorted in which case it will be extremely slow.

If you have the freedom to decide how the num/name-pairs can be modeled I strongly suggest to design a specific class for those as already pointed out by *iavanish*. Be sure to implement `equals` and `hashCode` accordingly and keep in mind that when also implementing the `Comparable` interface it should reflect the *natural order* which should be in sync with the `equals` method. So when calling `equals` for two objects (5, a) and (5, b) and the result is `false` the `compareTo` method should *not* return 0. If you need a particular order that is not natural go for `Comparator` instead.

Sorting using the Streams API is to be prefered when working with a large number of values so that the initialization and integer boxing/unboxing overhead can be disregarded. In that case also `.parallel()` could additionally be used in order to gain even more speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int[] num={5,2,10,12,4};
  String[] name={"a","b","g","c","r"};

  // During sorting int array...
  //Use indexes to switch the characters as well from     string array
  //Eg. If 2 from int array is shifting at index 0 from index 1 
 //Then also shift String[1] to String [0]
```